# Android 13 Soft Keyboard and CandidateView

Tags: java, android, android-13

[image: enter image description henter image description hereere]

Here is 2 Image in one plus android 13 device. In keyboard top menu bar is not visible.
also input text suggestion from CandidateView not display too.

same keyboard and code working in android 12, please help me in this to figure out what android 13 changes.

I tried downgrade android sdk version to 32 and android dependency to 29.

Top menu view and candidate suggestion view color(Black and white) changes also work but emoji, gif, sticker icon and suggestion text not visible.

I checked this more and found that the keyboard is perfect in landscape mode but when I turn device that top menu turn invisible.

Thanks

Comment: Solution here: https://github.com/klausw/hackerskeyboard/issues/901. More precisely, look at this commit: https://github.com/klausw/hackerskeyboard/commit/c504b79f3783cbf1f6228014fdd0bad288ad0d2c.

Comment: setCandidatesViewShown(true) this work in start input method but its throw null object on first start and app crash on rotate device landscape to portrait. null object is menuview in this case